# Token aware load balancing with Astyanax on Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

Some background:
we are using Cassandra 2.0.9 with Astyanax 2.0.2, replication factor is set to 4, there are 256 vnodes per node.

When running with round robin connection pool, everything looks good and Cassandra nodes are evenly loaded.

When we switch to token aware connection pool, 4 nodes start having significantly higher load, after a minute we have to go back to round robin due to latencies.

We have installed OpsCenter - data distribution looks good.
Connection pool configuration with round robin looks like this:

- latency score strategy: EMA
- latencyAwareScoreThreshold: 2.0
- latencyAwareUpdateInterval: 1000
- latencyAwareResetInterval: 0
- latencyAwareWindowSize: 50

Any ideas how can we fix this and start using round robin connection pooling?

Comment: can you clarify?  your question says you are using round robin connection pool in both cases.